# User Validation issue (Like event)-NODE JS

Tags: node.js

I have a code that allows to a user to like a post created by author ,the problem of this code that is always pushing value to `mongodb` even the if the user is already existing in DB and also already liked the post

what I tried is below and I didn't succeed explained with some comments

```
const like = function (req, res, next) {

  User.findOne({ 'events._id': req.params.id }).exec((err, obj) => {
    if (!obj) return console.log("Does not exist.", null);
    //console.log(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.events.length; i++) {
      if (obj.events[i]._id === req.params.id) {
        console.log("Like here 1")
        if (obj.events[i].likes.length) {
          for (let j = 0; j < obj.events[i].likes.length; j++) {
            console.log("like here 2")
            if (obj.events[i].likes[j].by !== req.session.user ) {
              console.log("data will be pushed")
              obj.events[i].likes.push({ by: req.session.user });
              obj.notifications.push({
                msg: `@${req.session.user} liked your post.`,
                link: `/u/${req.body.author}`,
                time: new Date()
              });
              obj = new User(obj);
              obj.save(err => {
                console.log(err, true);
              });
            } else if (obj.events[i].likes[j].by === req.session.user ) {
              console.log("here nothing will be pushed")
              console.log('already liked')
              return res.json('Already Liked!!')
            }
          }
        } else  {
          console.log("in this case if(obj.events[i].likes.length) =0")
          obj.events[i].likes.push({ by: req.session.user });
          obj.notifications.push({
            msg: `@${req.session.user} liked your post.`,
            link: `/u/${req.body.author}`,
            time: new Date()
          });
          obj = new User(obj);
          obj.save(err => {
            console.log(err, true);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

the result that I get always is this

[image]

What I'm looking for is below :

1- when a user click on the button, the code check of the user already liked the post or not using `obj.events[i].likes[j].by !== req.session.user`

2- if the user already exists and liked the post then `return liked`

3- if the 
`obj.events[i].likes.length` =0 then a new value is pushed to db

Hope I explained everything
could it be possible to help me with this issue?

Comment: It feels like you're tying to ask about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824657/how-do-i-update-mongodb-document-fields-only-if-they-dont-exist so if that's the case: there's already a SO post for that. If not, can you explain (in your post) how your needs are different?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you for your answer it is similar to what you mention `{'title.de': {$exists : false}}  or true` but  how can I update my code using that , could it be possible to help me ?

Comment: again: please make changes to your post: comments asking for more details are a sign that your post is missing details that should be added in so that _everyone_ who might potentially help answer your question has the information they need. I'm highly unlikely to be the person to post an answer, but someone else will.

Comment: Thx done I just updated my question

Comment: Any help please, thank you